# Find all elements with className in children prop

Tags: reactjs, children

As the title explains, I would like to find all the elements in the children prop and perform an action on all of them, the children prop can includes elements, strings etc.:

```
const newChildren = Children.toArray(children).map((child) => {
  const isItem =
    isValidElement(child) &&
    child.props.className.includes('item');

  if (isItem) {
    console.log('is an item, do something with it');
  }

  return child;
});
```

Get the error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
```

Comment: what is type of `child.props.className` ?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire The children can be anything, but what TypeScript is stating is: `React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal`

Comment: Seems at least one item doesn't have `props.className`

Answer (score 0):

Looks as if a simple safe navigation operator would do the trick:

```
  const isItem =
    isValidElement(child) &&
    child.props?.className?.includes('item');
```